# Как сверстать такой прямоуглольник?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать такой прямоуглольник?

Comment: Круглый блок с серым фоном (внутри которого ещё 2 круга - белый и чёрный) сверху частично наложен на белый прямоугольник.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

нарисовать круг, и выставить position: absolute.